# Touch Event in Scrollview ios

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Scrolling is not stopping when I touch over the contact labels. How can I add this feature for this open project.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/scroller

If I touch the background, it is working perfectly. I would like to have same thing for the contacts labels too.

Basically, it uses scrollview and there is an animation while scrolling. I can not make stop it when I touch over the labels.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I am unfamiliar with the scroller project, maybe this can at least get you on the right path.

The likely reason why touching the contacts isn't stopping the scrolling is because the labels are receiving their own touch events for their own purpose, which is probably the desired behavior, since you would probably want to touch one of the contacts and have it do something.  It's possible that since the touch events are being intercepted in that view for that reason, that you can not interact with the scroll view using the same event.

You may need to set the userInteractionEnabled property of the view surrounding each contact to false until the scrollview has stopped scrolling.  There are several ways you could do this, but this might be enough to get you started on a good solution.

Comment: You are awesome!! When I disabled user interaction from labels, it is working. I just need to check if scrolling ended. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

My condition may be similar with yours.

I build a scroll view in storyboard and a view is added to the scroll view.All of my UI component was placed in the content view including two textfields.Generally speaking, I would like to rewrite the `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method, and end editing actions in this view.
However,rewrite the method in scrollview's superview has little help.But when I subclass the view and rewrite that method in this subclass Every thing is OK.

According to my condition ,subclass the view and rewrite `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`.Process the logic in view level.